# What type of doctor does hormone replacement therapy?

Tags: medicine, testosterone

I show all the signs of low testosterone even though I am just 23. What type of specialist do I need to see to get tested for low testosterone levels and get treated if needed?

Comment: Hi @Sam! Per our FAQ, general health questions are off-topic on this site.